# Get original base64 filename of uploaded image (Dropzone)

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

How do i get the original filename of the image that is uploaded.
With uploaded i mean once the image is cropped to the thumbnail inside Dropzone. I can only get the base64 string of the cropped image, instead i need the original base64 string of the image.

here is some of my code:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, { // Make the whole body a dropzone
                url: "/target-url", // Set the url
                parallelUploads: 20,
                previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
                uploadMultiple: true,
                autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
                previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
                clickable: ".fileinput-button", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
                init: function() {
                    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {

                        console.log(file.name);

                    });
                }

            });
```

This instead gives me the normal filename, not the base64 string of the uploaded image.

Someone knows how to do this?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Post the code you already have, there are arguments, and generally one of those arguments is the file, and then you'd get the name with `file.name`

Comment: If you want base64 I'm guessing you have to use a canvas and convert the image to base64, something like this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127717/submitting-dropzone-js-with-base64-encoding-file

Comment: @adeneo That is working :) however how do you deal with multiple images?

Answer (score 2):

The parameter is an HTML5 [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object. 
The **preview file** can be accessed via (within your init function):

```
file.previewElement
```

The **base64 encoded file** can be accessed via:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
// Closure to capture the file information.
reader.onload = function(e) { 
    //get the base64 url
    var base64URL = e.target.result;
    //print to console
    console.log(base64URL);  
};
// Read in the image file as a data URL.
reader.readAsDataURL(asdf);
```